# Chain Select Form for Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, contact-form

I use Contact Form 7 plugin for creating useful web contact forms.

Now I need to create more specific form. I'm sure you will understand what I want to say if you look at the title.

Shortly when I write "What do you need ?" to first box (question) it must open up different second box (question) according answer of the first question.

Have I got any chance to develop easily Contact Form 7 to do this ? Also any different plugin is suitable to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please refer to this post
[Can I have conditional fields using Contact Form 7 plugin in Wordpress?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7412261/can-i-have-conditional-fields-using-contact-form-7-plugin-in-wordpress)

Nicole's answer was
http://wordpress.org/support/topic/plugin-contact-form-7-this-is-how-to-showhide-fields-with-jquery?replies=8

Comment: Thank you Robert. I'll absolutely examine that post. But I didn't see Nicole's answer. Anyway, that is awesome post. Do you believe that I can make a form with chain select using the steps in there ? If yes perfect. I love this site :)